# Are FME2013 and 64bit Background Geoprocessing of ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 compatible?

Tags: geoprocessing, arcgis-10.1, fme-form, 32bit, 64bit

We are running ArcGIS 10.1 sp1 and have installed **[64-bit background geoprocessing](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/10/31/announcing-64-bit-geoprocessing/)**.  We are also upgrading to FME 2013.  I know in the past we have had to install the 32-bit version of FME due to compatibility issues - I think regarding writing to File Geodatabases.

Now that ArcGIS has 64-bit background processing available, am I able to install the 64-bit version of FME?  Or do I still need to install the 32-bit version in order to have full compatibility?  Does the 64-bit background geoprocessing even have anything to do with the compatibility?

Comment: see: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fmetalk/4tHzn8Yx4GE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install both the fme 64 and 32 bit.  ESRI doesn't have a 64 bit application. You will extend the fme32 with arcgis.
No the 64 bit background processing won't use fme.
I have both installed and use each with extended software.